# Как подключить библиотеки GLEW GLFW GLM в проекте на С#

Tags: c#, opengl

Как подключить  библиотеки GLEW GLFW в проекте на С#
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Я просто скопировал ваш вопрос в Гугл](http://www.cyberforum.ru/opengl/thread1523852.html)

Comment: @eastwing Это для С++, а не С#

Comment: В очередной раз был невнимателен, пардон ) Может, [так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276389/confused-over-dll-entry-points-entry-point-not-found-exception)?

Comment: В последнее время я в таких случаях стал в первую очередь в [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=opengl) искать.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Попытался, но выдает ошибку(выложил скрин)